# Window.location.href post parameters to actionresult asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, windows, location, href

I try to post textbox value to actionresult in asp.net mvc

**Javascript:**

```
function OnButtonClick() {
    var data= {
        TextBox: TextBox.GetValue()
    };
    var PostData= data.TextBox;

    window.location.href = "Home/MyActionResult?Page=data" + PostData;
}
```

**ActionResult**

```
public ActionResult MyActionResult(string PostData)
{
    return view();
}
```

Whenever I post data to `Home/MyACtionResult` , PostData is always `null`,

What am I missing ?

How can I post textbox value to actionresult?

Comment: location.href is a GET, use Ajax

Comment: if i use ajax , i can not change url , i want to use window.location

Comment: Of course you can. Do some research. Jquery history for example. You need to EITHER use Ajax or a form with method post OR change the server to accept a GET

Comment: @user3389856 are you trying to do a POST or a GET?

Answer (score 5):

Try with this:

```
window.location.href = "Home/MyActionResult?Page=data&PostData=" + PostData;
```

Comment: You cannot post using a GET but at least you fixed the parameter name

Comment: @mplungjan The action method is not marked with HttpPostAttribute, so I assume it is not a post.

Comment: Count the number of times "post" occurs in the question?

Comment: I'm interpreting those *post* as a verb which means *send*

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var url = '@Url.Action("../Home/MyActionResult")' + '?Page='+data+'&'+PostData;
window.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of passing data is a bad approach. Please try to look into another code approach. This will not work for huge data, urls, secured data.

Comment: Why a negative point. What is wrong in this. Do you think the way how the user is passing the data is right? I suggested that the approach of passing data is not right.

Think about 
1. Security 2. Huge data passing 3. network urls length

My intention was to change the this approach for code first instead of adding solution on bad code approach.

Comment: You are principally right (bad approach for passing data -> I also think so), but it don't help to know (say), that i's a bad way. Can you post an example here, how to pass parameters without passing it with "?"  in the url?

Answer (score 0):

With window.location.href you can't use POST method.
But here is simple trick if you don't want to you GET method.

```html
You can use cookies and then 
function OnButtonClick() {
    setCookie("param1",value1,30);
    setCookie("param2",value2,30); // and so on, fetch input names and values using javascript 
    window.location.href = "Home/MyActionResult"
}
```

And then you can get cookies values from your MyActionResult page and use it.

Ofcource you have to include setCookie function as well in your page.

Comment: also in your MyActionResultpage, you can destroy given cookies that helped you to post data to your new page without "?", querystring OR GET method.